# Google Domain Verification in Open Source Project

Tags: security, google-apps

Are there any security concerns with checking in the google domain verification html file to an open source project? The site is hosted on heroku and all source is freely available on github to benefit the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing to be concerned about as far as security with the Google verification HTML file.  It's just a hash that they generate that only has a meaning to them.  It can't be used to find out anything else about your site or Google account.

Comment: That is what I thought, just wanted to be sure. Thanks :).